# How to get all the top level htmlelements from C# WebBrowser?

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control

I want to show the DOM as it is on the web browser with all comments and html, head, body, etc.. preserve its structure. Currently, I can only start from node html. Document.All didnt help.
The only way I can see is webBrowser1.Document.Body but I would miss the commentss, head etc.. Then if I go with Document.All then that gives me all the nodes.

Comment: Why not simply save the result of [`WebClient.DownloadString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring.aspx)?

Comment: I need to use the web browser... the user will be using the web browser.

Comment: Well, you first need to describe to us what you are trying to do - the question as it currently stands cannot be answered.

Comment: More please... The description doesn't explain _why_ you must use `WebBrowser`. It doesn't explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I need to use the web browser because the user navigates with that. I need to show the dom of the currently loaded page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only choice with the WebBrowser control to get what you want is to use `Document.All`. Although this gives all elements not just top-level, each element has a `.Parent` element property so you can loop through them (or use Linq) and get only the ones that have `<body>` or `<head>` as the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), it support Xpath so you can get any node as you want.

Comment: I need to use the WebBrowser.

Comment: @Devela - Why? What's the use case?

Comment: Because I need to grab the code from the DOM and display it in a tree. All of it. @Oded

Comment: Still don't understand what you mean :(

Comment: @Devela, how does that prevent you from using HAP?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by hienvd_csuit, I think HTML Agility Pack is your best option. If you still want to use the `WebBrowser`, a possible solution is to access the unmanaged DOM directly, using `dynamic` (requires .NET 4+). For instance you can do something like this:

```
dynamic dom = wb.Document.DomDocument;
foreach (dynamic node in dom.childNodes)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("{0} - {1} - {2}", node.nodeType, node.nodeName, node.nodeValue);
}
```

Of course, you need to know the structure of the DOM, since intellisense doesn't work on dynamic objects; you can find some information about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to query (there is a property somewhere) if a particular item has a child node or not, also, you can query if it is a parent node or if a particular item has a parent or not, and if it does, discard, and you can keep querying for parent such as item.parent.parent (pls check intellisense for exact object/property names) and if it returns nothing, it means there is only one parent (assuming item.parent doesnt return nothing), and you can organize how many levels deep the nodes can/must be. So based on the child or parent checking method (or both) you can choose to either include it in your collection or discard it.

Of course, you might get many "P" tags or DIV/SPAN tag's as your top level nodes/items. So, i'm assuming there is a chance you will not want these, so feel free to discard them and query their children.